How do I set VSCode native window and tab color?
On a Mac, I am using Settings > Native Tabs.
Inside each tab, the colors are fine (using themes etc).
On the Mac, far too many windows are gray - hard to distinguish.  I would like the top (project-tab) area to be something other than gray (see screenshot below).  I was not able to find (or recognize) this in settings > workbench.colorCustomizations.

